# Convert string "2021-03-23T19:30:00+08:00" to date format dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to convert string "2021-03-23T19:30:00+08:00" to simple format date dd-MM-yyyy in java programming. Hope you guy could give me any suggestion with java version 8 or above.

Comment: Java [date time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) tutorial.

Comment: Could even do that with string substring, split or regex. Show your attempts so far

Comment: This page has a decent explanation: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_date.asp

Comment: Easy enough if your requirements are clear. Assuming that you want the date in Cambodia time zone, `OffsetDateTime.parse("2021-03-23T19:30:00+08:00").atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Phnom_Penh")).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu"))` yields `23-03-2021` (please break up in more code lines introducing auxiliary variables).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not particularly simple.

If the code that does this is located in, say, Kiribati, which is in timezone UTC+1400. It would be the 24th of march at the time you stated.

So, should the answer be `2021-03-24`, or `2021-03-23`, or 'depending on where you run this code, either the 24th or the 23rd'?

Best to first convert your string into what it actually represents, by using the classes in the `java.time` package: First use a `DateTimeFormatter` to make a `ZonedDateTime` object. You can then either place this at a zone, or strip the zone from it and turn it into a `LocalDateTime`, or just ask straight up for the month, day, and year for that, and format it using `.format`, and again a `DateTimeFormatter` to define the output format.

With these APIs, whichever way you care the answer the 'kiribati' issue, it's easy.

Answer (score -1):

```
Three Ways to Solve.

**Way-1**
---------
You have to parse the string to Date then format that Date

String date = "2021-03-23T19:30:00+08:00";

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter1.format(formatter.parse(date)));

you will get the output as

2012-12-01


**2nd Way**
--------

OffsetDateTime.parse( "2012-12-31T13:32:56.483+13:00" ).toLocalDate();


**3rd Way**
---------
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
 Date date = dateFormat.parse("2017-04-26T20:55:00.000Z");//You will get date object relative to server/client timezone wherever it is parsed
 DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); //If you need time just put specific format for time like 'HH:mm:ss'
 String dateStr = formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: Do not longer suggest the usage of the old SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Class `java.util.Date` and class `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` have been replaced by classes from the `java.time` package, which was introduced in Java 8. Since the OP requests a solution suitable for Java 8 and above, I would say your answer is not really suitable.

Comment: If the OP wants the date in the string irrespective of the UTC offset in the string, the Way 2 would be nice and simple (ways 1 and 3 are not recommended under any circumstances). However, for the vast majority of situations taking the date from the string and ignoring the offset does not make sense. We should convert the time into the time zone expected by the audience first. java.time (the modern Java date and time API to which `OffsetDateTime` and `LocalDate` belong) can do that easily too.

Answer (score -1):

Hope, below code will help you to parse the datetime:

`BELOW Java_8`:

```
String string = "2021-03-23T19:30:00+08:00";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"), Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

FOR `Java_8`:

```
String string = "2021-03-23T19:30:00+08:00";
DateTimeFormatter currentPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"); 
DateTimeFormatter toBeFormattedPattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(string, currentPattern);
String output = datetime.format(toBeFormattedPattern);
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I have updated the answer, and it is now compatible with Java 8. @Abra